Change the reference style
In the chemmacro documentation, I saw that we could customize the nomenclature of reactions via the \chemsetup command.
Is there a possibility to keep this customization during a reference (I saw that it was kept in the list of reactions but a priori not in the body of the text)
Add : I also just realized that the reference does not have the right number: in the reactions environment, the 1st reaction is noted {1} while when I call the reference, it is noted 2
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824

\begin{document}
\chemsetup[reactions]{before-tag=Reac \textbf}
\begin{reactions}
    A   &-> B \\"\label{rxn:react1}"
    A   &-> C \\"\label{rxn:react2}"
    D   &-> A \\"\label{rxn:react3}"
\end{reactions}

Dans la réaction~\ref{rxn:react1} ...
\end{document}


chemmacro uses internally the package mathtools for tagging, with the tag form reaction. You should then use \eqref, instead of \ref.
To use your customization, you need
\usetagform{reaction}

But probably, you have also math formulas that you don't want their tags to be modified. You must then change the tag form locally, for example with a dedicated command:
\newcommand*{\reactref}[1]{\bgroup\usetagform{reaction}\eqref{#1}\egroup}

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824

\newcommand*{\reactref}[1]{\bgroup\usetagform{reaction}\eqref{#1}\egroup}

\begin{document}
\chemsetup[reactions]{before-tag=Reac \textbf}
\begin{reactions}
    A   &-> B \\"\label{rxn:react1}"
    A   &-> C \\"\label{rxn:react2}"
    D   &-> A \\"\label{rxn:react3}"
\end{reactions}

% \usetagform{reaction}

Dans la réaction~\reactref{rxn:react1}\dots

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  a~math~equation
\end{equation}

Dans l'équation~\eqref{eq:1}\dots

\end{document}


